# Perl Grepping from an Array

Tags: regex, perl

I need to grep a value from an array.
For example i have a values

```
@a=('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/h.cpp', branches/Main/utils.pl');
```

@Array = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/h.cpp', branches/Main/utils.pl','branches/Soft/B2/c.tct', 'branches/Docs/A1/b.txt');

Now, i need to loop @a and find each value matches to @Array. For Example

Comment: Please show the sourcecode you tried to use. `grep` is the way to go.

Comment: "It's not working" is a terrible way to explain the problem. What, exactly, have you tried? What unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solved My Question. Thanks to all especially @zdim for the valuable time and support

```
   my @SVNFILES = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/b.txt');
   my @paths = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/b.txt',
'branches/Docs/A1/b.txt', 'branches/Soft/B2/c.tct');

            foreach my $svn (@SVNFILES)
            {
            chomp ($svn);
            my $m = grep { /$svn/ } (@paths);

                            if ( $m eq '0' ) {
                            print "Files Mismatch\n";
                            exit 1;
                            }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).  You'd do it the exact same way as in the `More::ListUtils` example below, except for having `grep` instead of `any`. You can also shorten it to

```
 my $got_it  = grep { /$str/ } @paths;
 my @matches = grep { /$str/ } @paths;
```

This by default tests with `/m` against `$_`, each element of the list in turn. The `$str` and `@paths` are the same as below.

---

You can use the module `More::ListUtils` as well.  Its function `any` returns true/false depending on whether the condition in the block is satisfied for *any* element in the list, ie. whether there was a match in this case.

```
use warnings;   
use strict;

use Most::ListUtils;

my $str = 'branches/Soft/a.txt';

my @paths = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/b.txt',
    'branches/Docs/A1/b.txt', 'branches/Soft/B2/c.tct');

my $got_match = any { $_ =~ m/$str/ } @paths;
```

With the list above, containing the `$str`, the `$got_match` is `1`.

Or you can roll it by hand and catch the match as well

```
foreach my $p (@paths) {
    print "Found it: $1\n" if $p =~ m/($str)/;
}
```

This does print out the match.

**Note** that the strings you show in your example *do not* contain the one to match.  I added it to my list for a test.  Without it in the list no match is found in either of the examples.

---

To test for more than one string, with the added sample

```
my @strings = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/h.cpp', 'branches/Main/utils.pl');
my @paths = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/h.cpp', 'branches/Main/utils.pl',
     'branches/Soft/B2/c.tct', 'branches/Docs/A1/b.txt');

foreach my $str (@strings) {
    foreach my $p (@paths) {
        print "Found it: $1\n" if $p =~ m/($str)/;
    }
    # Or, instead of the foreach loop above use
    # my $match = grep { /$str/ } @paths;
    # print "Matched for $str\n" if $match;
}
```

This prints

```
Found it: branches/Soft/a.txt
Found it: branches/Soft/h.cpp
Found it: branches/Main/utils.pl
```

When the lines with `grep` are uncommented and `foreach` ones commented out I get the corresponding prints for the same strings.

Comment: thanks. i was trying with more than one value in $str (Ofcourse in an array @str) in the above example and i did used foreach to loop and grep for each value from an array but i couldnt succeed.

Comment: @John  Can you show those strings you were trying?  Edit your question and type them in so that I can see them. It is hard for me to know what is wrong without information.

Comment: In tha same above example. Instead of $str, i'm using @str = ('branches/Soft/a.txt', 'branches/Soft/b.txt'); Now, i need to loop it and found each string has present in array paths or not

Comment: @John  You cannot do that. The "pattern" looked for has to be a scalar (single string), not an array. Having an array in there, like `m/@str/`,  will do something completely different, not what you want.  If you want to check more strings, whether each exists in an array, you would use code like above for each one in turn (in a separate overall loop, for example).

Comment: No. I i'm not doing m/arraystr/. I'm looping the arraystr (foreach my $str arraystr), then using the code my $got_match = any { $_ =~ m/$str/ } arraypaths; and checking with if condition that $got_match is defined or not for each value in arraystr. But i guess i'm missing something.. Please note that i used array to poin (at) symbol since its not allowing more than one (at) in Comments..

Comment: @John Ah, OK, sorry.  That should work ...?  The first one you show should match, the second one not (different directories in path of the second element, with `Docs/A1`). I think that with `any` it should be 0 or 1 (not undefined in any case).  I just tested, `grep` prints 0 as well when there is no match. Let me know what exactly you are doing if you can't get it to work.

Comment: i have edited my question. and that is my exact requirement.

Comment: @John  I just tested it and it works as it should. I'll add it to the post.   Run this from the command line, where I use "at_" instead of 'at' symbol:     perl -wE 'at_m = ("branches/Soft/a.txt", "branches/Soft/h.cpp", "branches/Main/utils.pl"); at_Array = ("branches/Soft/a.txt", "branches/Soft/h.cpp", "branches/Main/utils.pl", "branches/Soft/B2/c.tct", "branches/Docs/A1/b.txt"); for $str (at_m) { $m = grep { /$str/ } (at_Array); say "Match for $str" if $m; }'

Comment: @John  Added it to the end of the post, for both `grep` and the manual `foreach` example.

Answer (score 1):

The <s>slashes</s> dot in `$a` will pose a problem so you either have to escape <s>them</s> it when doing regex match or use a simple `eq` to find the matches:

Regex match with `$a` escaped:

```
my @matches = grep { /\Q$a\E/ } @array;
```

Simple comparison with "equals":

```
my @matches = grep { $_ eq $a } @array;
```

With your sample data both will give an empty array `@matches` because there is no match.

Comment: I tried the above solutions. It worked for grepping one value from the array. But it didnt worked in case of more than one value. I did used foreach loop to search for each value in an array but i couldnt succeed.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape characters like '/' and '.' in any regex when you need it as a character.

Likewise :

```
$a="branches\/Soft\/a\.txt"
```

Retry whatever you did with either grep or perl with that. If it still doesn't work, tell us precisely what you tried.

Comment: But also: Don't use `$a`. It's not a good variable name, and it's used by `sort`.